# importing extenral js file to angular

Tags: javascript, angular7

I have been adding my javascript files this way in angular:

```
 "scripts": ["src/assets/js/core/jquery.min.js",
          "src/assets/js/core/bootstrap-material-design.min.js",
          "src/assets/js/plugins/moment.min.js",
          "src/assets/js/core/popper.min.js"],
```

is there another method to add external javascript files to angluar 7 besides this one. I tried this but it doesnt seem to have any effect

Answer (score 0):

first, you should install your library with npm. then the library is being added to your node_modules folder, in your project.

now:

if you want to import js files into the angular project, first you should check the version of angular, if you are using version 2 and 4 , you should write like this :

```
          "scripts": [ "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" ]
```

and if you are using version upper than 4, like 5,6 or 7 you should write like this :

```
          "scripts": [ "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" ]
```

in this example i import jquery into the angular project. i hope, it works